# Calculate the trajectories of each ship based on an AIS dataset

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table of kinematic data (position reports from vessels). The table has the following rows:

```
row name:   type:               Description:
timestamp   double precision    timestamp in UNIX epochs (seconds from 1/1/1970)
type        integer             AIS message type 
mmsi        integer             MMSI identifier for vessel
status      integer             Navigational status
lon         double precision    Longitude (georeference: WGS 1984)
lat         double precision    Latitude  (georeference: WGS 1984)
heading     integer             True heading in degrees (0-359), relative to true north
turn        double precision    Rate of turn, right or left, 0 to 720 degrees per minute
speed       double precision    Speed over ground in knots (allowed values: 0-102.2 knots)
course      double precision    Course over ground (allowed values: 0-359.9 degrees).
```

After I imported the data, I added one more row of type geometry formed using the lon, lat and timestamp rows:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('public', 'gis_may', 'geom_time', 4326, 'POINTZ', 3);
UPDATE public.gis_may SET geom_time = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat, gis_may.timestamp ), 4326),4326);
```

I have to calculate the trajectories of every ship, based on this data. I tried using the code below:

```
CREATE TABLE ship_trajectories AS SELECT st_makeline(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(lon::REAL, lat::REAL, gis_may.timestamp), 4326)) as traj
FROM gis_may
GROUP BY mmsi;
```

…but the problem is, this code returns only one linestring/trajectory based only on the coordinates of each ship and does not take into account the times the ship stopped moving.

I think the solution to this is using the row: `status` (I searched and found what navigational status is: https://help.marinetraffic.com/hc/en-us/articles/203990998-What-is-the-significance-of-the-AIS-Navigational-Status-Values-). When `status` is 0 it means the ship is moving and when it is 1 it means it is anchored so it no longer forms a trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a project which solved the same problem by first looking at all AIS-points to determine trajectory breaking-points. If you think that the AIS-variable `status` is enough for your purposes, then good for you. You could check each instance of status changing to 0. Be aware that AIS-data has other status values too. See [this](https://help.marinetraffic.com/hc/en-us/articles/203990998-What-is-the-significance-of-the-AIS-Navigational-Status-Values-).

What if, within each mmsi, you would like to mark the row when a ship goes from status 1 to status 0. This would create the points of delimitation for your trajectories to begin with. Look at this after first adding your longitude-latitude coordinations as a *point* geometry called `gis_point`:

```
-- Make a point geometry and work with those.
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'gis_may', 'gis_point', 4326, 'POINT', 2);
UPDATE gis_may SET gis_point = ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),
                4326), 4326);

-- Look ahead to keep stuff within the same mmsi. Create a switch for when the status changes:
CREATE TABLE lookahead AS
SELECT aislag.mmsi, aislag.timestamp1, aislag.gis_point, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (aislag.ts2 - aislag.ts1)) AS timediff, aislag.g,
       CASE WHEN aislag.status = '1' AND aislag.newstatus ='0' THEN 'Start' ELSE '.' END AS newtrajectory
FROM
    (SELECT mmsi, timestamp as timestamp1, status, gis_point,
            LEAD(mini_c.timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY mmsi, timestamp) AS timestamp2,
            LEAD(mini_c.mmsi) OVER (ORDER BY mmsi, timestamp) AS mmsi2,
            mini_c.status AS status,
            LEAD(mini_c.status) OVER (ORDER BY mmsi, timestamp) AS newstatus
     FROM mini_c) AS aislag
     WHERE aislag.mmsi = aislag.mmsi2
```

I've added a lagged time-variable too. Maybe you would like to enlarge the status-switcher to include observations with obsene time-differences to next-following AIS-point for that same ship. Now that you have your delimiters, you can create a new `id` for rows in `lookahead` which follows the `mmsi, ts`-sorting. Then make a new table `trajectories` with pairs of those `id`s as `id1` and  `id2` from a lagged selection on `lookahead WHERE newstatus = 'Start'` so that you get a row for each distance between switches of status. That table basically has trajectories as observations. Joining on the lookahead you can make your line-geometries per trijectory with `ST_Makeline(gis_point)` using `WHERE newid BETWEEN trajectories.is1 AND trajectories.id2` and `GROUP BY mmsi`.

Sorry for not writing out all the code.

A more advanced approach is to use the actual AIS-data to look at rolling average speeds and distances over time for each `mmsi` to determine where the ship appears to be standing still for longer periods. The logic above to distinguish delimiters for trajectories would than apply in the same way, only that the AIS-variable switch of `status` is exchanged for a calculation of behavioral patterns of ships.

Best of luck